# Conditional Permutations with allowed repeating

Tags: permutations

Let's say we have four elements `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D`.

How can I calculate number of all possible permutations (order matters) for set of 4, if repetitions are allowed, but it is required to have at least one `B` and one `C` element in each set?

How can I calculate similar task for same elements, same conditions, but for set of 5?

Comment: Hint: inclusion/exclusion ideas work here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The total orderings are $4^4$, since each blank has $4$ choices. Now calculate the orderings which have no $B’s$ or no *C’s*:

$$n(\bar B \cup \bar C) = n(\bar B) + n(\bar C) - n(\bar B \cap \bar C) \\ =3^4 + 3^4 -2^4 \\ =146
 $$

Hence, our desired answer is  $4^4 -146 =110$

You can use a similar procedure for any number of blanks.

Comment: Thank you very much. Very logical approach. Can't ask for more.